# different between class library and portable class library in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, class-library

There are different types of Class libraries available in Visual Studio such as Silverlight Class Library, Portable Class library and Class Library. What are the differences between these types? How can we determine the type of a Class library with `File.dll` file? How can we change a Class library from own type to another type of Class library?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The **Portable Class Library** project type enables you to write and build managed assemblies that work on more than one Microsoft platform, whereas the "normal" **Class Library** project type doesn't.

"Microsoft platforms" include .NET Framework, Windows Phone, .NET for Windows Store Apps, Silverlight, Xbox; all in various versions or flavors.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg597391)

Go through [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/imilovanovic/archive/2012/08/31/vs2012---how-to-manually-convert-.net-class-library-to.aspx) for converting from one class library to another type. (See also: [this relevant SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11265132).)

Comment: +1 @Jayram: thanks. How can determine type of dll file. (entityframework class library and portable class library).

Comment: This might be helpful too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265132/is-there-any-guidance-on-converting-existing-net-class-libraries-to-portable-li

Comment: Honestly these definitions, although entirely correct, contain a lot of noise with regard to the actual question. The entire first paragraph also applies to PCLs, and all but the first sentence of the second one also apply to classic CLs. In other words, I think you can reasonably simplify your answer to just quoting one sentence without loss of information.

Comment: @JayramSingh Alright; this was just a suggestion though so feel free to revert -- this feels like a non-trivial change but I think it's still very much the same answer. I also updated the terminology per the official reference (".NET Framework Platform" -> "Microsoft platform") and updated the link to the source (now targeting the latest version of the document, which changed). And added a link to the relevant SO question regarding your conversion tip.

Comment: @tne thanks so much. Yeah this looks much better to understand.