# Specify .NET version in Build Configuration in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have a Solution file (.Sln) in Visual Studio for my Application. Application development started back in .NET 3.0. Later it was decided to provide application in .NET 3.0 and .NET 4.0.

Since there wasn't an option (I was not present at that time) so two solution files were created.

- App_NET30.Sln
- App_NET40.Sln

Later came a requirement to support .NET 4.5 as well. So one more file was created

- App_NET45.Sln

Respective Solution files are opened using Visual Studio version

- App_NET30.Sln - Opened in VS 2008
- App_NET40.Sln - Opened in VS 2010
- App_NET45.Sln - Opened in VS 2010

Now, somehow, this does not seem a good way to me. **There has to be a neat and clean way of doing this**. Like doing it all in a single solution file

I tried to create a single solution and defined various build configurations in the file and changed `Target Framework` in each build configuration. But it did not persist.

**What can be a way to have a single solution file and achieve all that I desire ?**

Comment: No simple way with VS2010 afaiaa.Shame you can't use VS2013 SP2 or later... it has Shared Projects which address this very issue. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30638495/106159

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thanks ! Sad to hear that..