# C# sharing Objects between projects

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Solution with 2 Projects...

Project A has Following
   A - Reference Third Party DLL (Which has a Class Called "Response")
   B - A Class which uses above DLL and returns the "Response" Object from a Method Called "GetResponse"

Now Project B Calls The Class From Project A Like This....

```
Response r = ProjectA.Class.GetResponse();
```

This will return a Error, because I dont have "Third party" reference in my project B.

I rather not ship my third party DLL to all of my other projects just to get the reference to **Response** Object from Third party **DLL**.

so is there anyway of doing it without having to add the 3rd party reference to Project B?

Comment: You're obviously trying to use the `Response` class here, so it simply *must* be defined. You need the reference.

Comment: yes, I can reference it....but anyway to Map Response Object to Project B without having to reference the entire  DLL?

Comment: In newer versions of VS/.NET you can use Shared Projects, which will compile the shared code into each project. This may be suitable for your needs, but may come with type casting/conversion issues. More info @ http://stackoverflow.com/q/30634753/16391

Comment: Also, if B calls A, its already implicitly referencing the assemblies that A references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your project is using objects defined in the third party DLL, it has to be referenced directly as well.

If you want to avoid this, you can wrap the `Response` object in a custom object defined in Project B, creating methods and properties to expose anything necessary on the `Response` class. Remember, you can't expose the `Response` class directly, or the direct reference will be necessary again.

Of course, even with wrapping, when deploying your final DLL, the third party DLL will still be required, it just won't need to be directly referenced.