# Shared project with T4 template

Tags: c#, t4, shared-project

I am big fan of [shared projects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30634753/1997232) and I want to use T4 templates similarly: reference shared project in different solutions and get access to generated content without hassle.

How to make T4 templates work in shared projects?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So far the easiest way to organize it is to **link** `.tt` files:

- Move all templates into separate shared project;
- Do not reference this shared project! This is important and this is why previous step is essential. When shared project is referenced it's **not possible to link its files**!
- **Link** `.tt` files from it (drag them with <kbd>Alt</kbd> key into target project or use Add - Existing item - Open - combo option "As link").
- Now you should be able to set their `Custom Tool` property (in file options) as `TextTemplatingFileGenerator` in target project (which is not possible in shared project and the reason of all troubles).

Seems to work, though it's not really uses shared project feature. Shared project is only used as a container for `.tt` files (any other project will do, but shared project doesn't produce output, so it's better imho) which are linked to target project.