# c# how to use custom button in another project

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and created a new class project where I inherited a button and modified some it features. I now want to use this button in another project. In this project, I've added a reference to it but when I try adding it to the toolbox I'm told that there are no components in the dll for it to be added to toolbox.

Is it possible to add this button without going down the route of the windows form control library?

The reason I don't want to go down this route is that I don't really need a container and want full access to all the buttons properties in any project I use it.

Comment: could you please share any code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Full access to all properties? This sounds like [*shared project*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30634753/1997232) to me. We are using those to avoid all dll-related problems (you call dll as container, right?)

Answer (score 0):

In the blank space at the bottom of the toolbox (you may have to collapse everything first) you can right-click to bring up the toolbox context menu. Select "Choose Items" and browse to your button you created.

In case you haven't already I would create the new button class in a new class library project. Make sure that it is public or it will default to internal which means it can't be used outside that assembly. change to release mode and compile it. Use that dll