# how to share a common images folder with 2 .net solutions

Tags: c#, .net

solution 1
-project 1
--images

solution 2
-project 2
--images

I want the images folder to be common for both the solutions . is that possible ? if so how ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Create a [Shared Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30634753/what-is-the-difference-between-a-shared-project-and-a-class-library-in-visual-st) and include it in a project in each solution

Comment: or add the files in one project and add the files as Links to the other project

Comment: yeah, been there, done that ;) shared projects are imo better suited, as you only need to add the file once without the need to think about adding this file in the other project, too.

Answer (score 0):

Images are not by default a part of the assembly generated, so depending on the way you are using that image, you have to perform the following actions:

- If you are using *Resources*, you can simply drag-drop the image from a central folder to the `Resources.resx`, it will not copy the image, instead it will link it. You can do this for multiple solutions.
- If you are including images as *Content*, you have to add the image to your project by clicking *Add* > *Add Existing Item* from your project. The instead of clicking *Add* from the file chooser, you have to click *Add As Link* from the *Add* dropdown menu.
- A last option is to create a common project which you include in both your solutions. In that project you can add the images, which you can reference from both solutions.

Comment: in last option , you mean to say a 3rd solution which contains a shared project?  then how to achieve regular synchronization ?

Comment: What do you mean with regular synchronization?

Comment: i dont want to update the dll everytime i add a new​ image, how to achieve that?

Comment: You don't. You just add a reference to the assembly in your two solutions. Then you add the image, compile and you are done.

Comment: my question is how communication will be done from sol3 to sol1 and sol2 ?

Comment: Include the compiled assembly from 1 in 2 and 3.