# Assembly 'SharedProject1' is not referenced by this project

Tags: c#, wpf, reference, resourcedictionary

So I have a WPF project and a SharedProject in one solution.

The SharedProject has a ResourceDictionary file. I made a reference to the SharedProject from my WPF project.

[image]

But when I try to reference the ResourceDictionaryit gives the message: 'Assembly 'SharedProject1' is not referenced by this project'.

```
<Window x:Class="WPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ietstesten"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/SharedProject1;component/Dictionary1.xaml" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your `ResourceDictionary` to a `WPF Custom Control Library` project or a `WPF User Control Library` project and reference this one.

A `Shared Project` is not compiled:

[What is the difference between a Shared Project and a Class Library in Visual Studio 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30634753/what-is-the-difference-between-a-shared-project-and-a-class-library-in-visual-st)