# Visual Studio -> Shared TypeScript Library -> TS6059 File '' is not under 'rootDir' ''. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript, webpack, typescript2.0

We are using `Visual Studio 2017` and have two separate web projects that are supposed to share some `React` components written in `TypeScript`. There can also be shared `JavaScript` files and `CSS` files. For this we have created a `Shared Project` in Visual Studio.

[What is the difference between a Shared Project and a Class Library in Visual Studio 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30634753/what-is-the-difference-between-a-shared-project-and-a-class-library-in-visual-st)

Right now the project only has a single file with this information.

```
export const Types = {
    Type1: '1',
    Type2: '2',
    Type3: '3'
}
```

For testing I can reference it like this and Visual Studio will locate the file:

```
import { Types} from '../../../2/Constants/Types'
```

However when I then try to run `webpack` I get the following error:

> TS6059: File '/2/Constants/Types.ts' is not under
>   'rootDir' '/1'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source
>   files.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Found the problem in my `tsconfig.json`. I had the following value:

```
"rootDir": ".",
```

If I changed it to this it started working:

```
"rootDir": "../",
```

However the default value was this according to the handbook:

> common root directory is computed from the list of input files

After reading this I decided to remove the value altogether and let the compiler set the default value instead.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Answer (score 21):

I used the [rootDirs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#virtual-directories-with-rootdirs) compiler option for this purpose and it seems to work swell!

```
"rootDirs": [
  "../some/folder/outside",
  "src",
]
```