# Sharing code between projects using TypeScript and webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, awesome-typescript-loader

I want to share code between two TypeScript projects. I don't want to publish shared code to NPM-- just want to put shared code in one project and use it in another project. I'm using [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) and [awesome-ts-loader](https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader). Current folder structure (simplified) is like this:

```
/devroot/
  mainProject/
    tsconfig.json
    src/
      shared/
        SomeSharedTypes.ts
  apiProject/
    tsconfig.json
    webpack.config.js
    src/
      UseSomeSharedType.ts
```

In `UseSomeSharedType.ts`, I want to be able to import types from `SomeSharedTypes.ts`.

I tried an obvious solution like this:

```
import {SharedType} from '../../mainProject/src/shared/SomeSharedTypes'
```

But the TS compiler gave me this error:

> TS6059: File '/devroot/mainProject/src/shared/SomeSharedTypes.ts' is
>   not under 'rootDir' '/devroot/apiProject'. 'rootDir' is expected to
>   contain all source files.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The first idea I got from [this Medium article](https://netbasal.com/sexier-imports-in-typescript-e3c645bdd3c6), which was to use TypeScript's [non-relative module imports](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#relative-vs-non-relative-module-imports) feature. This would allow me to write my imports like this:

```
import {SharedType} from '@foo/SomeSharedTypes'
```

Using the techniques described in the article, I added a `paths` configuration to my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@foo/*": ["../mainProject/src/shared/*"],
    },
    "rootDir": "./",
    ...
  }
}
```

Then, again as the article recommends, for users of awesome-typescript-loader, I had to modify my `webpack.config.js` to add a resolution plugin:

```
const { TsConfigPathsPlugin } = require('awesome-typescript-loader');
. . .
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.ts'],
    plugins: [
      new TsConfigPathsPlugin(),
    ],
  }
```

Important: this plugin needs to go into the `resolve/plugins` section of the file, not the root-level "`plugins`" section!  If you put the resolver plugin in the wrong place, you'll get this error:

> resolver.ensureHook is not a function

The steps above got me further along in the process-- TypeScript was now able to find my files!--but I still got the same error later in webpack's execution: `'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.`

After a lot more Googling, I found a solution in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52351044/126352): instead of a single `rootDir` configuration, TS has a [`rootDirs`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#virtual-directories-with-rootdirs) setting that allows multiple roots. I removed my `rootDir` setting from `tsconfig.json` and added a `rootDirs` setting:

```
"rootDirs": [
  "./",
  "../mainProject",
],
```

Next, I ran into a webpack error on the other-project TypeScript file I was including:

> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:15)
>
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

After another hour of troubleshooting, I figured out that I need to tell the webpack loader about my new shared folder. Like this:

```
const path = require('path');
. . .
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
      loader: "awesome-typescript-loader",
      include: [
        __dirname,
        path.resolve(__dirname, "../mainProject/src/shared/")
      ],
      exclude: /node_modules/
    },
```

That worked!  The nice part about this solution is that I can refactor my folder structure without changing source code. All I'd need to change is `tsconfig.json` and `webpack.config.js`.

I'm admittedly new to using webpack and TypeScript, so there may be a better solution than the one above... but the one above worked for me!

Sharing the solution here to make it easier for the next developer to find it.

Comment: After I added `"baseUrl"`/`"paths"` to `tsconfig.json` and `loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'` and
```
    plugins: [
      new TsConfigPathsPlugin()
    ]
```
it seems to be enough, `rootDirs` and `include` not necessary. At least both `tsc` and `webpack` succeed.

Comment: Just wanted to chime in and thank you for pointing out "rootDirs" - that solved a lot of my headaches, as I wasn't aware that was an option!

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend using the [Nx workspace management](https://nx.dev/) tool as it is specifically build to solve these kind of setup issues. You can simply create a library within your repository that can then be imported everywhere (see: https://nx.dev/angular/tutorial/08-create-libs). Me and my team are heavily relying on Nx now for over 6 months and could not imagine managing a TypeScript repository without it, give it a try! https://nx.dev

If using Nx is not an option for you, you can model the way the implemented code-sharing:

1. Create a new folder
2. Add an `index.ts` file which exports everything that should be accessible from outside the library
3. Add an entry inside your `tsconfig.json` -> `compilerOptions` -> `paths` that points to the `index.ts` of your library
4. Import the shared code via the import name you specified inside the `tsconfig.json`