# How to import shared typescript code using create-react-app (no eject)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, create-react-app

I'm trying to achieve TypeScript code sharing in a create-react-app in non-eject mode, but I'm running into the infamous restriction that imports outside of `src` are not allowed:

> `You attempted to import ../../common/src/lib.ts which falls outside of the project src/ directory. [...]`

For the non-TypeScript case this has been [asked & answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44114436/1804173), but I can't get any of the solutions to work with TypeScript. Specifically the issues with the proposed solutions are:

- Setting `baseDir` in `ts-config.json`: Here create-react-app complains about: *Your project's `baseUrl` can only be set to `src` or `node_modules`. Create React App does not support other values at this time.*
- Approaches based on react-app-rewired: More promising. Disabling the `ModuleScopePlugin` gets me past the "attempted import outside src" error, but the problem now is that the loader of typescript files doesn't play along:

  [image]

  I have verified that the `.ts` itself is fine: Copying to `./src` and importing it from there works fine.

  I have also added `../../common/src` folder to the `includes` list in `ts-config.json`.

  My guess is that somehow the webpack loader configuration has a rule that prevents the TypeScript loader to transpile files that don't match its expected path patterns. How can this be fixed using react-app-rewired?
- Symlinking sources doesn't work either -- again with the same problem. Probably because webpack internally resolves the symlinks and sees the file in a path where the normal loader rules don't apply.
- Eject based solutions: I'd like not to eject for now, but I tried and I'm basically running into the same problem again.

I've also found other questions that sounded related but didn't answer the problem:

- [Create React App + Typescript In monorepo code sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59867657/1804173): Sounds basically like the same question, but it is not, because it is asking for the case of an ejected React app.
- [Sharing code between projects using TypeScript and webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52487113/1804173): Also addresses the code sharing problem, but not create-react-app specific, and I don't know if the solution can be transferred to create-react-app, because it requires manual webpack config control.

---

Re-using TypeScript typings in a mono repo seems to be a fairly reasonable pattern. Am I missing something or why is the create-react-app making this so difficult?

---

To reproduce: My code is basically 100% what you get from

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript
```

with one import to external added.

Comment: I think the monorepo solution makes most sense, since it's symlinking under the hood and would work perfectly fine for a non ejected app. https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/workspaces/ you just have to make sure that you run `tsc` before you import your types

Comment: @azium Hm, I tried various symlinking patterns, but since webpack internally resolves these symlinks I always ended up with the error above.

Comment: instead of importing `../something` you would import the module as if it were in your node_modules folder `import { YourType } from 'your-local-module'`

Comment: I have opened an upstream issue: [create-react-app should allow TypeScript imports outside `src`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8785)

Comment: This **[example](https://github.com/oklas/react-app-rewire-alias/tree/2f1888e56ae48057cda6ba87f0af2aab66514372/example/main)** using create-reat-app 4.0 with typescript imports file NearSrc.tsx outside of src demonstrate worked solution (**[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66107598/2969544)**)

Answer (score 17):

You could use [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/tree/master/packages/craco) (create-react-app config override) to override the webpack config (abstracted as part of CRA) without ejecting.
Additionally you could use `ts-loader` to reference non-transpiled ts code directly in external projects (e.g. if you wanted to reference/use shared code/lib as part of a mono-repo).

Assuming your CRA app is in the `client` directory your project structure is like the following:

```
client/
|--src/
|--package.json
shared/
|--package.json
|--(ts files)
package.json
```

---

1. 

```sh
cd client
yarn add -D @craco/craco ts-loader
```

2. create a `craco.config.js` file in the `client/` (CRA) directory
3. ensure the `craco.config.js` has the following content

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: webpackConfig => {

      // ts-loader is required to reference external typescript projects/files (non-transpiled)
      webpackConfig.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          transpileOnly: true,
          configFile: 'tsconfig.json',
        },
      })
      
      return webpackConfig;
    }
  }
};
```

4. Replace `react-scripts` commands in `client/package.json` with `craco`

```
/* client/package.json */

"scripts": {
-   "start": "react-scripts start",
+   "start": "craco start",
-   "build": "react-scripts build",
+   "build": "craco build"
-   "test": "react-scripts test",
+   "test": "craco test"
}
```

Comment: Note that CRACO doesn't officially support create-react-app 4.0 and [its maintainer doesn't seem to be in the mood to maintain it long term](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/issues/205#issuecomment-715528156). Its annoying that these work-arounds against CRA's limiting defaults break with every major release.

Comment: CRACO now supports CRA 4.* but I had a conflict with ts-loader having a later webpack as a dependency. Instead of adding a rule and installing ts-loader, I modified CRA's own rule to not have the `include` field which limits it to `src` dir. You may want some additional checks in case the indexes change, but essentially do this instead of pushing new rule: `delete webpackConfig.module.rules[1].oneOf[2].include;`

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE**: Since react-app-rewired is only maintained passively and doesn't support CRA versions 2+ (we are are three major versions later at the time of writing), I would no longer recommend this approach.

---

After more hours of experimenting and reading up on GitHub issues, I finally have a working solution. Big thanks to BirukDmitry who made [this very helpful post on GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8143#issuecomment-566523002). Step-by-step guide:

1. Install react-app-rewired and customize-cra

   ```
    npm i react-app-rewired customize-cra --save-dev
   ```
2. Configure react-app-rewird with a minimal `config-overrides.js` like this:

   ```js
   const { removeModuleScopePlugin, override, babelInclude } = require("customize-cra");
   const path = require("path");

   module.exports = override(
     removeModuleScopePlugin(),        // (1)
     babelInclude([
       path.resolve("src"),
       path.resolve("../common/src"),  // (2)
     ])
   );
   ```

   Setting (1) is similar to what is needed for getting around the import-outside-src limitation in general (see [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44114436/1804173)).

   Setting (2) is crucial though to enabled babel-transpilation (and thus, including TS type stripping I presume) for other paths as well. This is where you have to put add your paths from which you want to import.
3. No adaptations needed for `tsconfig.json`.
4. Import using relative paths, e.g., `import * as mymodule from '../../common/src/mymodule'`.

Comment: The `babelInclude` configuration was all that I was missing to resolve the aforementioned error. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

@bluenote10 solution did the trick!

There was only one issue in step #2 that prevents Babel from  transpilling ts files from ../../common/src
That is modified version  of @bluenote10's code (that finally worked for me)

---

1. Install react-app-rewired and customize-cra

   ```
    npm i react-app-rewired customize-cra --save-dev
   ```
2. Configure react-app-rewird with a minimal `config-overrides.js` like this:

   ```js
    const { removeModuleScopePlugin, override, babelInclude } = require("customize-cra");
    const path = require("path");

    module.exports = function (config, env) {

        return Object.assign( // We need Object.assign() to not to loose initial config 
          config,
          override(
            removeModuleScopePlugin(),       //1
            babelInclude([
              path.resolve('src'),
              path.resolve('../common/src'), //2
            ])
          )(config, env)
        )
      }
   ```

   Setting (1) is similar to what is needed for getting around the import-outside-src limitation in general (see [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44114436/1804173)).

   Setting (2) is crucial though to enabled babel-transpilation (and thus, including TS type stripping I presume) for other paths as well. This is where you have to put add your paths from which you want to import.
3. No adaptations needed for `tsconfig.json`.
4. Import using relative paths, e.g., `import * as mymodule from '../../common/src/mymodule'`.

Answer (score 1):

The alias solution for craco or rewired *create-react-app* is **[react-app-alias](https://github.com/oklas/react-app-alias)** for systems as: [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/blob/master/packages/craco), [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired), [customize-cra](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra)

According docs of mentioned systems replace `react-scripts` in `package.json` and configure next:

### **react-app-rewired**

```js
// config-overrides.js
const {aliasWebpack, aliasJest} = require('react-app-alias')

const options = {} // default is empty for most cases

module.exports = aliasWebpack(options)
module.exports.jest = aliasJest(options)
```

### craco

```
// craco.config.js
const {CracoAliasPlugin} = require('react-app-alias')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: CracoAliasPlugin,
      options: {}
    }
  ]
}
```

### all

Configure aliases in json like this:

```js
// tsconfig.paths.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "example/*": ["example/src/*"],
      "@library/*": ["library/src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

And add this file in `extends` section of main typescript config file:

```js
// tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json",
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Weird, react-app-rewired and customize-cra don't officially support CRA 4, right? Does it only work by chance, or just with a limited feature set?

Comment: This solution doesn't solve the issue. 
The issue is that we want to import shared code outside the root. not near src.
If you have multiple projects and want to share components between those projects but you don't want to publish your components to npm

Comment: @oklas v1.1.0 of cra or ts or what?

Comment: @user158443, imports from outside of root folder for CRA (using craco or rewired cra) with typescript is available in *react-app-rewire-alias* from version **v1.1.0**

Comment: @bluenote10, that was some bug in CRA exact version v4.0, however it was worked also for v4.0 with some additional actions ([more details here](https://github.com/oklas/react-app-rewire-alias/issues/9)), it was fixed in CRA v4.1 and since that it is worked.

Answer (score 0):

question where does `../../common/src/mymodule` lives at ?
is it another project ?
If it is another project why dont you link'em

- inside common code project run `npm link`
- inside the project that will use the common code: `npm link common-project`

If there are not two different projects. why does it has to be outside of src ?

The link you posted [The create-react-app imports restriction outside of src directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory)
and your case/problem are two totally different thing, plus they be tripping so hard. let me give you and idea of that problem and yours.

As we already know CRA creates a SPA single page app. which means that there is only one single html file. everything happens at the `index.html` which is located at `<project>/public/index.html`. If we compile the code we'll notice something the end bundle might look some like this

```
build
--static
----js
----css
----media
--index.html
--...more hashed crap...
public
src
```

and by default `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` is set to "/"
WHAT??  yes look let me show you. there is an old say a picture explains more than 1000 words.
[image]

if we look at the image that according to its path it is located at `./src/styles/imageSlack.jpg` or some.
So what if we console.log it.

[image]

WHAAAT!! where they do that at ? one thing you can do to test my theory is if you `console.log(process.env.PUBLIC_URL)` any where in yow code. now here is the big diference between this and that.

Browsers natively do not know Typescript.

So either you set yow code inside `src` and we end happy or 
follow the separate of concerns principle and we create an npm package with the shared code and just imported as any other module.