# Use files as content resource in multiple projects: build action: content

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resources

I have one project that has content resources (files with property `build action: content`) and `copy if newer`

Is this the right way to do it? Right now I must reference this project, so all files are copied and then I can use them using the known path.

It seems wrong.

1. Shouldn't it only copy the files needed?
2. Now I have a "reference is not in use" - warning, since I don't use any code from that project.

The files should be located outside the .dll or .exe, so updating them is easy.

I am contemplating writing my own library which only copies a file when it is newer and when it is called for and gives back the path.

Comment: Normally you should create a library (dll) for resources. There is [shared project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30634753/1997232) (seems more suitable for you). External files are typically a part of installation project.

Comment: This sounds interesting. When I use a shared project, how do I access the files / resources inside it?