# Shared project doesn't have packages.config

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

My shared project has no packages.config, so where is it storing the packages that it uses?

Also, when I edit references, the tabs are empty - I can't select anything.

What's going on here?

Comment: Shared projects have no direct references themselves (packages, assembly references, etc..), the project that "references" them have the external packages, assembly references, etc.. So need Json support, add Newtonsoft to **all** the project(s) that includes the shared project, and now you can use Newtonsoft within your shared code.

Answer (score 2):

> Shared Projects let you write common code that is referenced by a
>   number of different application projects. The code is compiled as part
>   of each referencing project and can include compiler directives to
>   help incorporate platform-specific functionality into the shared code
>   base.

Source: [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/shared-projects?tabs=vsmac) where you could find all the details.
 Beside that there are few related thread on SO, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30634753/what-is-the-difference-between-a-shared-project-and-a-class-library-in-visual-st).

P.S.: [Official Xamarin documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/code-sharing) nicely covering the code sharing options.

Comment: How do I reference Mono.Android without a version range?

Comment: So why doesn't ____ANDROID____ compiler directive work in my shared project if it's not a proper project?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/building-cross-platform-applications/platform-divergence-abstraction-divergent-implementation#android