# How to have a common HttpContext for ASP.NET WebForms, MVC and CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, owin

I'm working on a Nuget library which can be used for web applications (WebForms, MVC, CORE) and will be published for both .NetFramework and .NetStandard.

In my library I need to access the HttpContext for reading the Request and also for redirecting and writing in the Response object.

What's the best way to have a common HttpContext for all three frameworks WebForms, MVC and CORE?

Note that Microsoft.Owin is not compatible with .NetStandard and also in WebForms and MVC there is a System.Web.HttpContextBase class which is completely different in .NETCore projects and there we have Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext.

Comment: Simple answer: you cannot. `System.Web.*` is not compatible at all with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*`.

Answer (score 0):

Your library could be organized this way:

1. Define adapter interfaces (over *HTTP context and etc*) in [shared source project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30634753/what-is-the-difference-between-a-shared-project-and-a-class-library-in-visual-st)
2. Define implementations of all those interface in concreate Core or Classic project - create both. There you should have 3 projects in your solution.
3. Now your library is 4th project it should be [multitarget](http://blog.peterritchie.com/Multi-targeting-in-Visual-Studio-2017/), use conditional symbols to enable or disable "Classic" or "Core" adapters. Use adapters to access "*Http Context and etc*".

Comment: Actually, Interface was my first solution. But I didn't want to reinvent the HttpContext class because I need bunch of methods and properties in both Request and Response objects.