# Windows forms references and singleton with conflicted imported type

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, shared-project

I have a solution with the following projects:

- Model: A shared project with the model
- App1: A windows forms application
- App2: Another windows forms application

I'm trying to move some UserControl currently duplicated in both projects in a common project, called CommonUI. So:

- Model
- CommonUI: Referencing Model
- App1: Referencing Model and CommonUI
- App2: Referencing Model and CommonUI

But this got me many warnings like:

> The type 'AppState' in '[..]Model\AppState.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'AppState' in '[..]CommonUI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Using the type defined in '[..]Model\AppState.cs'

The problem is that AppState is a Singleton but it get duplicated, App1 see an instance and CommonUI see another instance has I now have 2 class called "AppState", one from the reference App1->Model and the other one from App1->CommonUI->Model.

What did I did wrong? Thanks

Comment: Have you put the same file duplicated in several projects ?

Comment: There are some user control duplicated but with different namespace. The application worked in this way for many years but now I need to merge these user control in some kind of "user control library"

Comment: Has the problem seem to be in the references between projects the only way i have to post some code is to zip the entire solution and upload it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AppState` is declared in `Model` which is a shared project. A shared project is [not a class library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30638495/397817). **The source code in a shared project is compiled into each project that references it**. In other words, if you have - say - 3 projects referencing the `Model` project, you will have declared the `AppState` class 3 times.

The solutions are to convert `Model` into a class library, or move `AppState` somewhere else.

In my experience, it is best to use Shared Projects only for small relatively inconsequential pieces of utility code which are to be built into an executable. Referencing them from libraries, or using them as libraries, is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference in case someone has the same problem.

The "problem" was the shared project. Shared project are directly injected in the referencing project so my code was injected in both the CommonUI project and the App1 project. 
The CommonUI project was compiled in a DLL (with model included) which was used by the App1 exe, so both the exe and the DLL contained Model code.

Switching from a shared project to a Class library resolved the issue.