# Reference shared project in multiple solutions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a solution `AddLog` which has only one project `AddLogClient` of type **shared project**. I created it by `right clicking on solution name->Add->Shared Project`.

[image]

I want to use this shared project in other solutions. When I go to another solution `MyApplication` and want to add a reference to `AddLogClient`, I can't see it in the list of shared projects, because it is not located in the same solution. When I try to browse for it, it expects a file in *.exe, .dll, .tlb, .olb, .olx* or *.winmd* format. Adding .dll file (from `bin` folder from `AddLogClient`) would not be acceptable because every developer has different repository checkout location and we can't use relative paths.

[image]

How can I reference shared project from other solutions? Both solutions are under SVN.

Comment: can't you use the `.csproj` file of `AddLogClient` to add it to your solution ?

Comment: A SharedProject is not actually what you think it means. It is a project used to share code between multiple assemblies, Take a look at this SO answer which clears that up: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30638495/4482565

Comment: If I reference `.csproj` file, then developers of solution `MyApplication` can still see and modify the code of `AddLogClient`. What if I don't want that? I just want to provide them some functions to use without exposing source code.

Comment: The standard way of doing this then is using a NuGet package. Consider using a private hosted Nuget server on your premises to isolate your codebase from the outside world.

Comment: Thank you for NuGet suggestion. Is there no way to use the same shared project from multiple solutions?

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of doing so, as @Sokopa suggested is through NuGet. For dev purposes, if you do not want to publish packages to Nuget servers, you can check the Generate Nuget Package on Build option and upon build it will create a nuget package in your build folder.

[check this guide from microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio?tabs=netcore-cli)