# Plugins and Sandboxing - Add reference to another project in solution

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, common-data-service

I have a plugin assembly I have registered to D365 CDS(cloud) and it runs fine.

I want to reference and use some classes in a separate project included in my solution in Visual Studio.

Adding the project as a reference will give File Not Found exceptions. I am able to add the individual classes using the Add Existing Item - Add Link option, but I would like to do it as a whole project reference instead of individual links. Is that possible without using ILMerge and how would I accomplish that?

Comment: I like to add the files from "Project A" to "Project B" as a `Linked File` Have you considered that? You can create a `SharedProject` type if you want to do this at the Project level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, I create a `SharedProject` in Visual Studio (2017). I put all my Business Logic into this Project (or Projects).

Then I can have a "Workflow" and a "UnitTest" project that each refer to that Shared Project.

[More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30634753/what-is-the-difference-between-a-shared-project-and-a-class-library-in-visual-st/30638495)

[image: Creating a Shared Project]