# how to Share a class between 3 project?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, shared-libraries

we have a SharedProject called SharedLib which contain a Simple class:

```
SharedLib
      ClassTest
           void test()
```

and we have 2 library project and we added SharedLib as a SharedProject:

```
Project A : SharedLib
ClassTest.Test // works fine

Project B : SharedLib
ClassTest.Test // works fine
```

until here everything is ok and working fine and class is shared between projects....
now we have another project called **TestProject**
and we add both **Project A** and **Project B**

```
TestProject : Project A, Project B
```

now if i use **ClassTest.Test** i get some error:

the type **ClassTest** exist in **Project A** and **Project B**

how i can fix this? can i set shared project in project b as a private or something similar?

Comment: How did you implement what you describe as `Project A : SharedLib`?

Comment: @Flydog57  <Import Project="..\SharedProject1\SharedProject1.projitems" Label="Shared"/>

Comment: Hmm. Is that in a `.csproj` file? What is a `.projitems` file?

Comment: It's a "Shared Project", which is different from a Class Library. https://stackoverflow.com/q/30634753/1043380 I'd love to hear why you chose to use that over a Class Library.

Comment: So the answer would probably be: use a library instead of a shared project.

Comment: @gunr2171 class library generate dll, is there a way to embed it in another library?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to merge them into one assembly?

Comment: @Fildor Some users don't want to have both libraries, so they were divided into two libraries, but now I need each other for some tasks. So I don't want the second library to be usable/viewable.