# Convert class library to portable class library

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

how to convert class library to portable class library in C#.
I have one class library project and i need to convert it to portable class library.

Comment: Class library itself is potable, you can add reference where you want to use it

Comment: @TirthakShah Incorrect.  A Win Phone 8 Store App can't reference a Windows Desktop.Class Library

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any guidance on converting existing .NET class libraries to portable libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265132/is-there-any-guidance-on-converting-existing-net-class-libraries-to-portable-li)

Answer (score 2):

You simply can't. Most of Class Library doesn't support in Portable Class Library example Class Library has system.cryptography while PCL hasn't.

You need to change it manually like replace system.cryptography with PCLCrypto and that mean you need to change your code also.